# Insert into else update from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this as i'm not able to get this working.
This is what happens:
My client uploads a (Rightmove) .blm file to server, Script unpacks the zip file and using a parser gets the properties into an array.. From here I'm able to INSERT into the database no problem however, i need this to update information in the database if exists otherwise insert as the blm file may contain New properties or existing ones editted.
The blm file only contains property information, there is no id etc so once inserted into the database i give it an id (propid) by means of auto incriment.

Please view the code below and hopefully you may have a suggestion that i could use to get this doing what i need it to do :)

```
foreach ($rmdata as $key => $properties) {    

$fields = array();   
$values = array();

foreach ($rmdata[$key] as $field=>$value) { 
if (!isset($value)) {       

}

if (isset($value)) {

$sql_props = mysql_query("SELECT propid FROM epsales");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_props)){
     $propid = $row["propid"];
}

$fields[] = $field; 
$values[] = "'".$value."'";

$array1 = array($field);
$array2 = array($value);

$sqlupdate = array_combine($array1, $array2);

foreach ($sqlupdate as $field=>$value) {
        $sql_update = "$field='$value', "; 
}
}   
}

$sql_fields = implode(', ', $fields);   
$sql_values = implode(', ', $values);


$sqlPropInsert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO epsales ('. $sql_fields .') VALUES ('.    $sql_values .') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET '. $sql_update .'');
```

Thank you for your time it's greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several notes:

1. `foreach ($rmdata[$key] as $field=>$value)` is the same as `foreach ($properties as $field=>$value)` in this context
2. the whole `if(isset($value))` thing can be avoided by starting that loop with `if(!$value) continue;`
3. When you select for the propid, you are selecting *every row* in the table, surely this is not what you intend to do, since you loop through them all and only every use the last one.
4. the section building the update section is flawed in a few ways. The simplest fix is to realize that you can achieve the correct result by re-combining the $fields and $values arrays after the loop (as shown later)
5. I can't readily see where you would get the conflict of keys, unless $rmdata will contain a propid if it's an update instead of an insert, or else if there is some other key and it's just being handled without explicitly seeing it in the code, which would be fine.

Below is code which I copied directly from yours and just modified to address these issues:

```
foreach ($rmdata as $properties) {     
  $fields = array();   
  $values = array();
  $updates = array();
  foreach ($properties as $field=>$value) { 
    if (!$value) continue;
    $fields[] = $field; 
    $values[] = "'".$value."'";
    $updates[] = $field . '="'.$value.'"';
  }     
  $sql_fields = implode(', ', $fields);   
  $sql_values = implode(', ', $values);
  $sql_updates = implode(', ', $updates);
  $sqlPropInsert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO epsales ('. $sql_fields .') VALUES ('.    $sql_values .') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET '. $sql_updates .'');
}
```

**note** that this technique requires *something* in the data to have a conflicting key in order for the ON DUPLICATE KEY to trigger. If there is some value in the data array which you can uniquely identify these rows by, that field should be a UNIQUE KEY in the database, which will 'cause this conflict to occur quite nicely.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.. had a little play and it's not working but i will look into it abit more shortly and let you know, Very grateful for your time Thank you! Kids to sort out then i'll return :)

Comment: Inserted your code and I've had a play about with it all and still no joy :( not sure if theres something i've missed and i've no idea why this won't work..

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about the nature of `$rmdata` and your database schema. Have you `echo`'d the queries to see if they are what you expect? In what way is it not working (not even compiling/inserting & never updating/etc)?

Comment: Hi ctrahey, Thank you so much for your help with this, i've got it sorted :) Used what you had done for me and added a few more lines plus altered the database slightly by changing one of the keys and now all working great thank you:) I really appriciate your time with this i'm so grateful! :)